# Error 2061 - Class Becomes "Undefined" When I Include A Header

Tags: c++

This is very strange and I can't get my head around what is causing it.... So I have two classes, Player and Enemy and a utility static class CollisionMgr.

I have an array of Enemies in the world class, I'd like to have a pointer to it in the Player class for collision detection. But the moment i try to #include the Enemy class in the player one, I get "Player undefined" error in the Enemy one.... I think it has to do with the header inclusions...

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    #include "mathlib.h"
    #include "md2model.h"
    #include "Object3DS.h"



    const float PLAYER_FORWARD_SPEED = 60.0f;
    const float PLAYER_HEADING_SPEED = 60.0f;

    class Player : public GameObject
    {
    public:

        Player(float r);
        ~Player();

        void loadModel(const char *filename);
        void drawModel();
        void drawBoundingWireframe();
        void passVisibleObjects(vector<Object3DS*> &vo);

    private:
    Entity3D entity;
MD2Model* player;

float modelRot;
float modelPitch;

Vector3 scale;
Vector3 pos;
Vector3 rot;

float forwardSpeed;
float heading;

float radius;


vector<Object3DS*> visibleObjects;

    };
```

And this is the Enemy class

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    #include "Player.h"
    #include "mathlib.h"
    #include "md2model.h"


    const float ENEMY_FORWARD_SPEED = 60.0f;
    const float ENEMY_HEADING_SPEED = 60.0f;

    class Enemy : public GameObject
    {
    public:

Enemy(Player* p, float r);
~Enemy();

void loadModel(const char *filename);
void drawModel();
void drawBoundingWireframe();


bool checkCollision();

void setPosition(Vector3 pos);
void setRotation(Vector3 r);
void setScale(Vector3 r);


void setSpeed(float s);
void setHeading(float h);
float getForwardSpeed();
float getHeading();
void rotateModel(float dx, float dy);
void resetRotation();

void setAnimation(char *filename);

Vector3 getPosition();
void moveEnemy(float elapsedTimeSec);

Entity3D entity;

void passVisibleObjects(vector<Object3DS*> &vo);



    private:
MD2Model* enemy;

Player* player;

float modelRot;
float modelPitch;

Vector3 scale;
Vector3 pos;
Vector3 rot;

float forwardSpeed;
float heading;

float radius;

vector<Object3DS*> visibleObjects;

    };
```

In the source files i include this static class with some collision functions:

```
    #pragma once


    #include <vector>
    #include "mathlib.h"
    #include "Object3DS.h"

    #include "Enemy.h"

    class CollisionMgr{


    public:

static vector<Object3DS*> findVisibleObjects(BoundingBox &viewingVolume,                 vector<Object3DS> &gameObjects, vector<Object3DS*> &visibleObjects);
static vector<Enemy*> findVisibleEnemies(BoundingBox &viewingVolume, vector<Enemy> &enemies, vector<Enemy*> &visibleEnemies);
static bool checkCollision(const Vector3 pos, const Vector3 forward, float radius, const vector<Object3DS*> &vo);
static double intersectRaySphere(Vector3 rO, Vector3 rV, Vector3 sO, double sR);


    };
```

All of these compile ok like this, but the moment I try to add #include "Enemy" in Player I get  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Player' inside the Enemy class....or if I include successfully Enemy and then try to include CollisionMgr.... there's some kind of conflict between them two and the definition of Player but I cant understand how to resolve it....

Am using VS2010 as my compiler..

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried re arranging the include statements but I really don't get what is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case of a circular dependency.  You will need to properly forward declare `Player` and `Enemy` and you will not be able to use their definitions in the opposite header file.  You can use them in the implementation file.  Here's an example:

Player.h

```
class Player
{
   // needs to know about Enemy
   void f(const Enemy& b);
};
```

Enemy.h

```
class Enemy
{
   // needs to know about Player 
   void f(const Player& a);
};
```

Including the header file in both locations will cause an error (like you are seeing):

Player.h

```
// This isn't going to work...
#include "Enemy.h"
class Player
{
   // needs to know about Enemy
   void f(const Enemy& b);
};
```

Enemy.h

```
// This isn't going to work...
#include "Player.h"

class Enemy
{
   // needs to know about Player 
   void f(const Player& a);
};
```

What is needed here is a "forward declaration" for `Player` and `Enemy` where appropriate, like this:

Player.h

```
// forward declaration:
class Enemy;

class Player
{
   // needs to know about Enemy
   void f(const Enemy& b);
};
```

Enemy.h

```
// forward declaration
class Player;

class Enemy
{
   // needs to know about Player 
   void f(const Player& a);
};
```

Then in the implementation files you can `#include` the appropriate headers to actually get the definitions of the objects in your compilation unit.